# JQuery UI drag & drop in Android

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I need some help about JQuery. Do you know if there's a jQuery plugin
to make jQuery UI drag&drop features to work on Android devices
without the need to modify the JS code?

Thxs

Answer (score 1):

Try http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag

The jquery.event.drag plugin claims to simulate the drag and drop functionality in a touch based environment. It calims to be a drop in replacement for the event drag and drop functionality.

Comment: You'll probably want to grab the drop code too: http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop